# access web server from outside network with public ip

Tags: apache, firewall

I have ubuntu virtual machine that connects to it remotely with public IP. I installed apache2 server on it. However I can't reach the server from the web browser. Can anyone tell what the security rule should I add to access the web page?

I tried

```
$sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"
```

and

```
@sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```

Comment: Is apache2 service running?

Comment: yes I tried `curl 127.0.0.1`  and returns the page  @AdlanArifZakaria

Comment: Try refer this [Cannot access Apache start page via “localhost” in web browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/753101/cannot-access-apache-start-page-via-localhost-in-web-browser)